# Trouble Creating Rails Stripe Subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, subscription

New-ish Ruby Rails programmer here, please help me learn.  I am having a difficult time creating a subscription in Stripe.  It is an app where schools will be registering to.  I already created a plan in Stripe with an ID called, 'reach' and I am able to create a Stripe Customer Token, but not a Subscription.

On my registration form (in views), I have a hidden_field_tag with the plan name as 'reach' which is passed through the URL, params.  I also have a hidden field in the form of the stripeToken.

I have a class called SchoolRegistration and the code underneath is here:

```
attr_accessor :stripeToken
attr_accessor :plan

def save_with_subscription

 if valid?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan, source: stripeToken)
   self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
   save!

 end
end
```

What I discovered recently is the `<%= hidden_field_tag :plan, params[:plan] %>` in my views is NOT saving to my database.  I can see it on my console when I hit submit, but it never gets saved to the database.  How can I save that in the database?

Controller:

```
    class SchoolRegistrationsController < ApplicationController

      def new
        @register = SchoolRegistration.new
      end

      def create
        @register = SchoolRegistration.new(register_params)


        if @register.save_with_subscription
          flash[:success] = "Congratulations!  You have registered your school!
          redirect_to new_user_registration_path

        else
          flash[:danger] = @register.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
          redirect_to new_registration_path
        end
      end

      private
        def register_params
params.require(:school_registration).permit(:name_of_person_completing_form, :email, :role_in_school, :school_name, :grade_levels, :street_name, :city, :state, :zip_code)
        end
    end
```

params.require is indented in my code...not sure why it wouldn't indent here.

JavaScript:

```
/* global $ Stripe */
//Document ready.
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

  //Set Stripe public key.
  var stripe = Stripe($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  var style = {
    base: {
      // Add your base input styles here. For example:
      fontSize: '16px',
      color: "#32325d",
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the customer that there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;

      } else {
        // Send the token to your server
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });
});

function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

I know it is probably obvious, I am just having a difficult time and I did check out the documentation.  Please help me learn and much thanks to all of you!  Let me know if you need more info or code - using Rails 5.

Comment: Put your `payment` related all code like `model` `controller` and `JavaScript`

Comment: Can you provide more information? What's the exact issue you're seeing? Is there an error or an exception when you try to create the customer object?

Comment: Thank you both for responding!  @fool I believe all the code should be there to check out.

@Ywain What I discovered recently is my `hidden_field_tag :plan, :params[:plan]` is not hitting the database and everything else is (new-bie question) how can I make sure that hidden_field_tag gets saved?  I can see it in my console when I hit submit on the form.

Answer (score 1):

create the subscription by associating the plan with the customer id witch you get when creating customer on stripe

```
Stripe::Subscription.create(
  :customer => "cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a",
  :items => [
    {
      :plan => "basic-monthly",
    },
  ],
)
```

For more information https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Would you place this code in the model file?

Comment: Also, from my form, the `<%= hidden_field_tag :plan, params[:plan] %>` is not saving to the database.  What do I have to write in my controller to save the hidden field tag part to the database?  Instance or local variable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm trying to give a full stripe implementation solution, you follow this step by step, all code is tested and go to the live site for testing [here the site](https://saas-app-3s.herokuapp.com/)

This example only Stripe payment

Add this on `view/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
just above
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Create environment variable with Stripe keys

```
STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY: sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

On the registration file, add the code below to the top of the file:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("<%= ENV['STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>");
</script>
```

And add this class on your form `cc_form`

Create a model for `payment` with references

```
rails g model Payment email:string token:string school_registration:references
```

Will generate a file under db like belo

```
class CreatePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :payments do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :token
      t.references :school_registration, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then

```
rake db:migrate
#=> model/SchoolRegistration.rb
#=> add these two lines
has_one :payment
accepts_nested_attributes_for :payment
```

On the `payment.rb`

```
    attr_accessor :card_number, :card_cvv, :card_expires_month, :card_expires_year
belongs_to :school_registration

def self.month_options
    Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.map { |name, i| ["#{i+1} - #{name}", i+1]}
end

def self.year_options
    (Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)).to_a
end

def process_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email, card: token

    Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id, amount: 1000, description: 'Premium', currency: 'usd' 
   #=> 1000 means 1000 cents that means 10 dollars
end
```

Now on your form

```
<%= fields_for( :payment ) do |p| %>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-left-padding">
            <%= p.label :card_number, "Card Number", data: {stripe: "label"} %>
            <%= p.text_field :card_number, class: "form-control", required: true, data: {stripe: 'number'} %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <%= p.label :card_cvv, "Card CVV", data: {stripe: "label"} %>
            <%= p.text_field :card_cvv, class: "form-control", required: true, data: {stripe: 'cvv'} %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <%= p.label :card_expires, "Caed Expires", data: {stripe: "label" } %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= p.select :card_expires_month, options_for_select(Payment.month_options),
                                                    { include_blank: 'Month' },
                                                    "data-stripe" => "exp-month",
                                                    class: "form-control", required: true %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= p.select :card_expires_year, options_for_select(Payment.year_options.push),
                                                { include_blank: 'Year' },
                                                class: "form-control",
                                                data: { stripe: "exp-year" }, required: true %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And now create `JS` file under `javascripts` folder named like `stripe.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var show_error, stripeResponseHandler, submitHandler;

    submitHandler = function (event) {

        var $form = $(event.target);
        $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
        //If Stripe was initialized correctly this will create a token using the credit card info
        if(Stripe){
            Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
        } else {
            show_error("Failed to load credit card processing functionality. Please reload this page in your browser.")
        }
        return false;
    };

    $(".cc_form").on('submit', submitHandler);
    stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
        var token, $form;
        $form = $('.cc_form');
        if (response.error) {
            console.log(response.error.message);
            show_error(response.error.message);
            $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            token = response.id;
            $form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"payment[token]\" />").val(token));
            $("[data-stripe=number]").remove();
            $("[data-stripe=cvv]").remove();
            $("[data-stripe=exp-year]").remove();
            $("[data-stripe=exp-month]").remove();
            $("[data-stripe=label]").remove();
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
        return false;
    };
    show_error = function (message) {
        if($("#flash-messages").size() < 1){
            $('div.container.main div:first').prepend("<div id='flash-messages'></div>")
        }
        $("#flash-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><div id="flash_alert">' + message + '</div></div>');
        $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
        return false;
    };
});
```

And finally, go to controller and add those lines

```
if @register.save
   @payment = Payment.new({email: params["school_registration"]["email"],
                token: params[:payment]["token"], school_registration_id: @register.id
            })
   flash[:error] = "Please check registration errors" unless @payment.valid?
   begin
      @payment.process_payment
      @payment.save
   rescue Exception => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      @register.destroy
      render :new and return #=> :new means your registration form
   end
else
    #=> Code 
end
```

This is actually one-time subscription and Stripe basic implementation if you implement this carefully and succeed you can whatever which you need.

And for more go to [Rails Checkout Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails)

Hope to help

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and help!